# How to remove duplicate rows before ingesting data into SQL Tables using Pentaho kettle

Tags: sql, migration, salesforce, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I was trying to get records from salesforce using salesforce input steps and ingesting in any SQL tables. During analysis, i came to know that duplicate records are also coming up from salesforce input steps.
The records are duplicate in sense that we have different records id, but the data for other fields are totally same.

EXAMPLES:

Id : 1
Name: Test Record 1
Price : 40

Id : 2
Name Test Record 1
Price 40

Id : 3
Name: Test Record 2
Price 60

Id : 4
Name: Test Record 2
Price 60

Is it possible if we have 2 similar records, one should be removed and only one be loaded in SQL tables? All i want that these should be handled before ingestion not through some transformation logic. Whhich steps should i have to use?

Tool: Pentaho

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with "Unique rows" ?

you can use "sort" then "Unique rows" placing the fields that will be unique.

Comment: yeah, i tried with unique rows (HashSet) that works for me
Thanks for your response